# How to implement PatternedRecurrence for making Office 365 REST API v2 Calendar Events

Tags: c#, calendar, outlook, ms-office, office365

Im trying to make PatternedRecurrence's so that a user can choose from 3 options, weekly, biweekly and monthly. However the code i've tried dosen't appear to be working, it posts to the API without error but does not appear anywhere on the test calendar, where as a non patterned one does appear on the calendar. THis is the code i've tried to set a weekly pattern.

```
NewEvent.Recurrence = new PatternedRecurrence();
NewEvent.Recurrence.Range = new RecurrenceRange();
NewEvent.Recurrence.Pattern = new RecurrencePattern();
NewEvent.Recurrence.Pattern.DaysOfWeek = new List<Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices.DayOfWeek>();

NewEvent.Recurrence.Range.Type = RecurrenceRangeType.EndDate;
NewEvent.Recurrence.Range.EndDate = start.AddYears(2).ToString();
NewEvent.Recurrence.Range.StartDate = start.ToString();
NewEvent.Recurrence.Pattern.Interval = 1;
NewEvent.Recurrence.Pattern.Type = RecurrencePatternType.Weekly;
NewEvent.Recurrence.Pattern.FirstDayOfWeek = Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices.DayOfWeek.Monday;

if (StartDay.ToString() == "Monday")
{NewEvent.Recurrence.Pattern.DaysOfWeek.Add(Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices.DayOfWeek.DayOfWeek.Monday); }
else if (StartDay.ToString() == "Tuesday")
{ NewEvent.Recurrence.Pattern.DaysOfWeek.Add(Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices.DayOfWeek.DayOfWeek.Tuesday); }

... for the rest of the days of the week
```

I've looked up the [referances](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#RecurrencePattern) for this but they aren't very helpful, although i'd think what i've written makes enough sense to work, apart from all them if statements, I couldn't figure a better way to convert from System.DayOfWeek to Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices.DayOfWeek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you have code to catch the execption? What's the response of the Request? We can use the Fiddler to track the response, if the recurrent appointment was created successfully, the response would contains the detail information about recurrence.

For example, here is a successful response:

```
{"@odata.context":"https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/$metadata#Me/Events/$entity","@odata.id":"https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Users('7f4f5db6-539f-45d2-b133-26a25318269a@60c1366c-1b8f-4fcd-a190-058bfd47bcb4')/Events('AQMkADVkMTY3YmNiLTJiMDctNGU5Yi05MmM4LTFjODZkNDgxMzhkMQBGAAAE19y4nS_cT5eu67AiEA77BwB6jcCHf_RcRZqcWLJUEog7AAACAQ0AAAB6jcCHf_RcRZqcWLJUEog7AAAAA_dGpgAAAA==')","@odata.etag":"W/\"eo3Ah3/kXEWanFiyVBKIOwAAA+SaVA==\"","Id":"AQMkADVkMTY3YmNiLTJiMDctNGU5Yi05MmM4LTFjODZkNDgxMzhkMQBGAAAE19y4nS_cT5eu67AiEA77BwB6jcCHf_RcRZqcWLJUEog7AAACAQ0AAAB6jcCHf_RcRZqcWLJUEog7AAAAA_dGpgAAAA==","CreatedDateTime":"2016-01-21T23:45:06.8317353-08:00","LastModifiedDateTime":"2016-01-21T23:45:07.0973601-08:00","ChangeKey":"eo3Ah3/kXEWanFiyVBKIOwAAA+SaVA==","Categories":[],"OriginalStartTimeZone":"Pacific Standard Time","OriginalEndTimeZone":"Pacific Standard Time","ResponseStatus":{"Response":"Organizer","Time":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"},"iCalUId":"040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00800000000A996F1CFE854D101000000000000000010000000D968C3A111A417438178343B150C0974","ReminderMinutesBeforeStart":15,"IsReminderOn":true,"HasAttachments":false,"Subject":"Sync up","Body":{"ContentType":"Text","Content":"Status updates, blocking issues, and next steps"},"BodyPreview":"Status updates, blocking issues, and next steps","Importance":"Normal","Sensitivity":"Normal","Start":{"DateTime":"2016-01-22T02:30:00.0000000","TimeZone":"Pacific Standard Time"},"End":{"DateTime":"2016-01-22T03:30:00.0000000","TimeZone":"Pacific Standard Time"},"Location":{"DisplayName":"Water cooler"},"IsAllDay":false,"IsCancelled":false,"IsOrganizer":true,"Recurrence":{"Pattern":{"Type":"Weekly","Interval":1,"Month":0,"DayOfMonth":0,"DaysOfWeek":["Friday"],"FirstDayOfWeek":"Sunday","Index":"First"},"Range":{"Type":"EndDate","StartDate":"2016-01-22","EndDate":"2017-01-22","RecurrenceTimeZone":"Pacific Standard Time","NumberOfOccurrences":0}},"ResponseRequested":true,"SeriesMasterId":null,"ShowAs":"Busy","Type":"SeriesMaster","Attendees":[],"Organizer":{"EmailAddress":{"Name":"Fei Xue","Address":"fx@msdnofficedev.onmicrosoft.com"}},"WebLink":"https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?ItemID=AQMkADVkMTY3YmNiLTJiMDctNGU5Yi05MmM4LTFjODZkNDgxMzhkMQBGAAAE19y4nS%2BcT5eu67AiEA77BwB6jcCHf%2BRcRZqcWLJUEog7AAACAQ0AAAB6jcCHf%2BRcRZqcWLJUEog7AAAAA%2BdGpgAAAA%3D%3D&exvsurl=1&viewmodel=ICalendarItemDetailsViewModelFactory"}
```

And Here is the code that created the recurrent appointment by weekly:

```
OutlookServicesClient client = new OutlookServicesClient(new Uri("https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0"),
                async () =>
                {
                    // Since we have it locally from the Session, just return it here.
                    return token;
                });


            Location location = new Location
            {
                DisplayName = "Water cooler"
            };

            // Create a description for the event    
            ItemBody body = new ItemBody
            {
                Content = "Status updates, blocking issues, and next steps",
                ContentType = BodyType.Text
            };

            // Create the event object
            DateTimeTimeZone start=new DateTimeTimeZone() ;
            string dateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss";
            string timeZone = "Pacific Standard Time";//"Eastern Standard Time";

            start.DateTime = new DateTime(2016, 1, 22, 14, 30, 0).ToString(dateTimeFormat);
            start.TimeZone = timeZone;

            DateTimeTimeZone end = new DateTimeTimeZone();
            end.DateTime = new DateTime(2016, 1, 22, 15, 30, 0).ToString(dateTimeFormat);
            end.TimeZone = timeZone;

            Event newEvent = new Event
            {
                Subject = "Sync up",
                Location = location,
                Start = start,
                End = end,
                Body = body
            };

            newEvent.Recurrence = new PatternedRecurrence();
            newEvent.Recurrence.Range = new RecurrenceRange();

            string dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
            newEvent.Recurrence.Range.EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1).ToString(dateFormat);
            newEvent.Recurrence.Range.StartDate = DateTime.Now.ToString(dateFormat);
            newEvent.Recurrence.Range.NumberOfOccurrences = 11;

            newEvent.Recurrence.Pattern = new RecurrencePattern();
            newEvent.Recurrence.Pattern.Type = RecurrencePatternType.Weekly;
            newEvent.Recurrence.Pattern.Interval = 1;
            newEvent.Recurrence.Pattern.DaysOfWeek= new List<Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices.DayOfWeek>() { Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices.DayOfWeek.Friday };
            // Add the event to the default calendar
            await client.Me.Events.AddEventAsync(newEvent);
```

Comment: Ahhh that's what I was doing wrong, the date format. Also stupid me, I had it sending on a background thread so the error wasn't getting pushed when I tested it. Thanks for the example, I tried looking for one but there isn't much out there. Also just wondering for a monthly recurrence would it just be to set ``DayOfMonth = userInput.Day`` instead of DaysOfWeek?

Comment: It seems you want to set the absolute monthly recurrence via. Besides setting the DayOfMonth, we also need to change the type of pattern to ecurrencePatternType.AbsoluteMonthly